# Conditional formatting in AppMaker table

Tags: google-app-maker

Have a data table in AppMaker and would like to do conditional formatting (Green to Red) in several columns based on the field value.

For example if ROI is over 40% give the number a dark green bg, 20% light green, < 0% red, etc.

Ideally I want to do a gradient like excel but that might be too complicated. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of assumptions, I am guessing your column is a vertical/horizontal/fixed panel or some other type of widget that you can edit in App Maker's property editor and that ROI is a field in your datasource. You can get this accomplished by setting 3 style classes in your 'Style Editor' like this:

```
.dark-green {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, darkgreen, green);
}
.light-green {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, lightgreen);
}
.red {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, darkred, red);
}
```

Then in the property editor for your widget go to 'Display' - 'styles' and bind your styles as follows:

```
@datasource.item.Percent === 0 ? 'red' : @datasource.item.Percent > 0 && @datasource.item.Percent <= 0.2 ? 'light-green' : @datasource.item.Percent > 0.2 ? 'dark-green' : ''
```

You can play around with the CSS for the background and such once you have your classes and binding for the styles accomplished to find a visual look that you like.

To apply this concept to the entire table row and still include the 'app-ListTableRow' and 'hoverAncestor' styling you would bind your table row styles as follows:

```
@datasource.item.Percent === 0 ? ['red','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : @datasource.item.Percent > 0 && @datasource.item.Percent <= 0.2 ? ['light-green','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : @datasource.item.Percent > 0.2 ? ['dark-green','app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor'] : ['app-ListTableRow','hoverAncestor']
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. A follow-up question: If I were to want the whole row to light up, is there a way to apply this to the row WITHOUT removing the pre-loaded styles. (hoverAncestor and app-ListTableRow). It seems like it's one or the other

Comment: @MikeWilliams please see my edited answer how to retain those styles and still apply the row highlighting to the whole row.