# Google APP MAKER, Changing a TRUE/FALSE statement in an image

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I am a small used dealership and we are using app maker to manage our inventory. In google app maker I created a simple table which shows my inventory along with reconditioning process (mechanic, detailing, inspection etc. On another page, I added some toggle switch, so when a task is completed, we turn the toggle on and in my list is shows ''true''. All I want to do, is when the statement is true, show a green circle and if false show a yellow circle. I have a basic of JavaScript and CSS, but i've been at it for 4 hours and still haven't figured out.

I tried a couple CSS styling and If/Else statements, but it has not worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would be helpful if you showed us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Please see a similar question with answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518944/is-it-possible-to-apply-conditional-formatting-in-google-app-maker?r=SearchResults.

Comment: Also another example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126309/conditional-formatting-in-appmaker-table?r=SearchResults.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in the following way:

1. Drag a label widget where you would like this dot to show in your
   UI.
2. Set the label widget horizontal and vertical size to 'fixed' and set
   the values to the same size, like 20px and 20px.
3. Introduce two css classes under your 'Global Style' css settings as follows:

   .condition-true {
     background-color: #0f9d58;
     border-radius: 50%;
   }
   .condition-false {
     background-color: #ea6100;
     border-radius: 50%;
   }
4. Return to your label in your canvas, make sure the text property does not contain anything. Find your 'styles' under the display property and put the following binding in this section:

   @datasource.item.YourItem ? ['condition-true'] : ['condition-false']
5. Adjust color settings in your css classes as necessary and adjust label size as necessary to your liking.

Comment: So I did exactly what you mentioned and it works, but when I toggle the switch back to ''false'' the color stays green. I've got two data sources, one for the vehicle information and one for the vehicle status. I built a relation between the two, and build my table with vehicle information data source. So I guess the mistake might be there as when I go and pick the Style the binding looks like this : datasource.item.VehicleStatus...MechInspection?  ['condition-true'] : ['condition-false']

Comment: @JimmyRuptash Is this a one-to-many relation between vehicle info and status, or one-to-one? The binding you used would suggest there are many statuses to each vehicle, I presume each one of those statuses is probably a separate step like mechanic, detailing, etc. If that is the case then this type of setup is highly dependent on how you are displaying these individual steps or if you are cumulatively just need to show 'complete' when all steps are completed. Please provide additional detail.

Comment: So the goal of this is to know where I am at in the vehicle reconditioning process. There's several steps : Mechanical Inspection, Mechanical repairs, Visual inspection, Detailing, Body Work and Pictures. When each step is complete. So I created vehicleStatus datasource and entered all the steps as a 'string' field. Then I created a MANY to MANY relation with VehicleInfo. Since every vehicle is different, we might do the detailing before the mechanic, the reason why I want to see in a table what step is completed. Maybe you have another easier solution.

Comment: @JimmyRuptash So what you will need to do in your vehicle info table is drag in a list widget (grid widget would be ok too) and in the widget setup wizard for the datasource selector find 'VehicleInfo: VehicleStatus (relation)' then in your list widget row panel drag in a label that will point to the VehicleStatus field for the name of the step and then drag in another label and for that label follow the above directions. This will result in table row showing your vehicle info and then a list for each status with complete or incomplete essentially.

Comment: Hi, so it's been a couple weeks since I worked on my app, a lot of work. What you said to me works great thank you for that! But, when I create a new car, the fields are blank. Once I toggle the switch it becomes true, and when toggled back it is false. How can I make it false when creating a car, as I know those things haven't been done on it yet. Or is there an IF statement that I could use ?

Comment: You should declare false as the default value in your model settings. That is the easiest way to handle this. Let me know if you are unsure how to do this.